# T-SQL Filter multiple values on one column based on another table column

Tags: sql-server, database, contains

Please help.

I am using SQL Server and familiar with `CONTAINS` keyword.

I have a table "Table1" with column values like

```
1,'bla1 bla2 bla3 String1 bla4 bla5 bla6 String2 bla7 bla8 bla9'
2,'bla3 String1 bla4 String2 bla7 bla8 bla1'
3,'bla3 String2 bla4 String3'
```

I have another table "Table2" with just one column, but with dynamic values like

```
1,bla1
2,string1
3,bla3
```

or

```
1,string2
2,bla5
3,bla1
4,bla4
```

I just wanted to return the rows in Table1 based on all the values present in the Table2, means it is not `OR`, but `AND` - all the values in Table2 should be present in Table1's column value (it can be in any order).

In the above example,

- if Table2's first set is checked against Table1, then it should return only the first 2 rows from Table1
- if Table2's second set is checked against Table1, then it should return only 1st row of Table1

**as one of the values in Table2 is not available in the Table1's column value**.

Since both these tables are temporary table variables, I am unable to add `FULL-TEXT INDEX` on them, else i could have used
`CONTAINS(Column, 'SearchString1 AND SearchString2 AND SearchString3 AND so on')`

The following code works fine but only upto 2 search strings. More than 2, its not working. For example, if I have like this in the below code

```
declare @str nvarchar(100) = ' Dr clark Nick '
```

---

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(Col NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Tab
SELECT ' Dr. Nick Clark' UNION ALL
SELECT ' Dr. Nick SPACE Clark' UNION ALL
SELECT ' Dr. Clark SPACE Nick' UNION ALL
SELECT ' Dr. Clark Nick' UNION ALL
SELECT ' Dr. Nick' UNION ALL
SELECT ' Dr. Clark '

declare @str nvarchar(100) = '  Nick clark '

set @str = ltrim(rtrim(@str))

DECLARE @Search1 VARCHAR(MAX), @Search2 VARCHAR(MAX) 

declare @t table(sno int, splitdata nvarchar(100))
insert into @t
SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by ltrim(rtrim(o.splitdata))) as sno,
    ltrim(rtrim(o.splitdata)) AS splitdata
FROM
    (SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,' ','</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS Filter)F1
     CROSS APPLY
          ( SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(MAX)') AS splitdata 
          FROM f1.Filter.nodes('X') AS fdata(D)
    ) O

SELECT @Search1 = COALESCE(@Search1 + '%', '') + Splitdata FROM @t order by sno
SELECT @Search2 = COALESCE(@Search2 + '%', '') + Splitdata FROM @t order by sno desc

select * from @tab where col like '%'+@Search1+'%' or col like '%'+@Search2+'%'
```

---

Comment: Would you expect a match if a row on table1 was "NickClarkNick" (no spaces)?

Comment: Any number of Nick or Clark is fine... But both Nick and Clark should be present... with or without spaces..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set nocount on;

declare @Tab table (col nvarchar(50));

insert @Tab (Col)
values (' Dr. Nick Clark')
     , (' Dr. Nick SPACE Clark')
     , (' Dr. Clark SPACE Nick')
     , (' Dr. Clark Nick')
     , (' Dr. Nick')
     , (' Dr. Clark ');

declare @str nvarchar(100) = '  Nick clark ';
set @str = ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(@str)) + ' ';

with Tally
as (
    select row_number() over (order by t1.column_id) as 'N'
      from sys.columns t1
      join sys.columns t2
        on 1=1
   )
, Needles
as (
    select substring(@str,N+1,charindex(' ',@str,N+1)-N-1) 'Needle'
      from Tally
     where N < len(@str)
       and substring(@str,N,1) = ' '
   )
, NotSelected
as (
    select tab.col
      from @tab tab
      join Needles
        on 1=1
     where charindex(Needles.Needle,tab.col) = 0
   )
   select Tab.Col
     from @Tab Tab
left join NotSelected
       on NotSelected.Col = Tab.Col
    where NotSelected.Col is null;
```

OK, so here's my approach: We turn your search string into a recordset, broken out by spaces. I use the Tally-table approach to this, but instead of a Real tally table, I use a Common Table Expression based off sys.columns ... basically gives me a table full of integers which I can use to quickly separate out your space-separated string into a recordset. I call it Needles because we're looking for these needles in the @tab haystack.

I create a cartesian recordset of the needles and haystack along with a `CHARINDEX` value of the first position of `needle` in `haystack`. Any value of zero tells me that needle isn't in haystack. This also is a common table expression called "NotSelected"- now listing all the @Tab.Col values where the needle isn't found.

Finally, a left join of the Not Selected rows with the full table will reveal all records NOT matching the Not Selected values.

Comment: Wow... It works... I just tested with values (permutation and combination).. 

Yet to understand the logic...

Thanks for the solution...

Comment: Understood the logic now...

Renamed the CTEs for my understanding as 'SNo_Gen', 'Search_Str_Splitter' and 'Not_Exists' (from top to down)....

Thanks once again.